# Thread Creation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've made an experiment on GOF Factory Method Pattern and use Threads for this.
I used the GOF Factory Method Pattern for dynamically create threads in C# .Net. The code structure is exactly the same described in the Factory Method pattern Example. I know creating new threads is not considered good practice. But sometimes you have to consider some not good enough practices to accomplish your requirements. I need to know that is it safe to create threads dynamically by this pattern or is there any better pattern or technology to create and manage threads in run time??? I am going to implement this in my project where I need to create several Threads in run time.

Comment: The .NET 4.0 TaskFactory class jumps to mind.  Other than  re-inventing that wheel and making it square, I guess that proves that using a factory is not "unsafe".

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks.. Please Write an answer.. so that i can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) .NET 4.0 TaskFactory Class is a useful tool for creating simultaneous Threads.

A task factory is represented by the System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory class, which creates Task objects, or the System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory class, which creates Task objects. Both classes contain methods that you can use to:

```
Create tasks and start them immediately. 

Create task continuations that start when any or all of an array of tasks complete. 

Create tasks that represent pairs of begin/end methods that follow the Asynchronous Programming Model.
```

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Creating new threads is not considered good practice. Consider utilizing Thread Pool. Thread Pool has many optimizations built into it. If you are using .Net 4.0 then you may also utilize Task Parallel Library.